# Can I trust the coefficients for time-invariant variables in feols()?

Tags: r, time-series, regression, panel-data

I have a panel dataset with 8000 units and 5 years. I use 10 explanatory variables, and 3 of them are time-invariant. Initially, I expected the fixed-effects regression to drop them, but feols() does not do this. This is the code I use:

```
{mod6111 <- feols(trans ~ wheat + pastS + horS + lpd + tri + henley + city +
         wjob1A + turn + rail + agroS + paupSRSD + enc10 | RC, data = rex51)}
```

I have read that these coefficients should be the same as the ones in the pooled model:

```
{mod6111pooled <- lm(trans ~ wheat + pastS + horS + lpd + tri + henley + city + 
              wjob1A + turn + rail + agroS + paupSRSD + enc10, data = rex51)}
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case and the coefficients are different. How can this be explained, and which estimate is more reliable?

Comment: What is `RC`? I suspect it’s the unit fixed effects, correct? Do the three variables exhibit any time variation within each unit?

Comment: Yes, RC is a geographic unit for fixed effects. There is no temporal variation in any of these variables.

Comment: Where have you read this? The "pooled" model using `lm()` should produce similar estimates if you include dummies for all geographic units.

Comment: You are right, thank you! The coefficients are very similar indeed.